# What is the best way to stop function from running multiple times in Js

Tags: javascript

```js
var emps;

function GetEmps(){
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='http://127.0.0.1:3001/GetEmployeeList';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(Http.responseText.length>0)
        {
            emps=JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
            
            for(let i=0;i<emps.length;i++)
            { 
                CreateElementsInPage(i);    
            }
                   
        }
    }

}
function CreateElementsInPage(id) {
    
    console.log(id);
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = emps[id].name;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    var newLine=document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(newLine);
}


GetEmps();
```

i am trying to create buttons dynamically. for every item in emps array, I want a button to appear in the DOM, but the "CreateElementsInPage" functions get called 4 times instead of 2 (suppose I have 2 items in emps) and I get 4 buttons [image]

Comment: What is inside the `emps` variable?

Comment: `onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();` <-- that preventDefault makes no sense, I expect it to throw an error.

Comment: You do not check to see if readyState is complete. Learn what onreadystatechange actually does

Comment: you can see it in the image attached

Comment: onreadystatechange = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); youre right, forgot to delete this line

Comment: The answers & comments re: onreadystatechange are right on, but… can you replace your use of XMLHttpRequest and use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead? There are a number of [fetch polyfills](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/625/top-5-best-javascript-polyfills-for-the-fetch-api) available in case you need to support poor old browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check request state inside your callback:

```
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if(Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      // Request is complete, do your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onreadystatechange` event function is triggered/called whenever the state of the connection is changed (`readyState`).

So you need to make sure that you create your button only when the connection is successful (done).

```
function GetEmps(){
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='http://127.0.0.1:3001/GetEmployeeList';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        // Make sure that the request is done before calling your button creation method
        if (Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           if(Http.responseText.length>0)
           {
               emps=JSON.parse(Http.responseText);

               for(let i=0;i<emps.length;i++)
               { 
                   CreateElementsInPage(i);    
               }

           }
       }
    }

}
```